# Como fazer Jquery datepicker aceitar apenas de meses e ano?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Como posso converter meu jQuery datepicker para aceitar apenas meses e anos ?

Comment: você está usando esse datepicker https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ ?

Comment: Exemplo usando o jQueryUI datepicker: http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/5106/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esse [jQuery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) você pode fazer um hack que funciona da seguinte maneira:

Adiciona none na class CSS dos dias conforme abaixo:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}
```

Logo depois você configura seu datepicker dessa maneira:

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });
```

Segue o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/DBpJe/6816/).

Comment: Boa ideia, o unico problema que vejo é caso haja outros datepickers na mesma página. Mas juntando uma `id` ou uma classe específica fica resolvido. `+1`

Comment: Bem colocado @Sergio, vou colocar essa observação :))

Comment: Muito bom era exatamente isso que precisava. Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Sei que foge um pouco da sua pergunta... mas utilizo seguinte plugin:

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#maxviewmode

Veja se é isso que vc precisa. Não tenho nada que reclamar dele... fora que ele é muito elegante!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fiz alguns testes aqui com esse datepicker, alem de ele ser muito bonito funciona lindamente rs .. +1 :D

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
$(".datepicker" ).datepicker({
  startView: 1,
  minViewMode: 1,
  maxViewMode: 3,
  format: "mm-yyyy",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
});
</script>
```